# Rails 4: Translate object attribute names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, localization

I have a custom form builder where checkbox is nested inside label. And the attribute name is localized using en.yml.

**CustomFormBuilder**

```
     def check_box(attribute_name, *args)
            @template.content_tag("attribute_name", super(attribute_name, *args) + @template.content_tag("i")
       + I18n.t(attribute_name), 
       :for => "#{@object_name}_#{attribute_name}")
        end
```

**en.yml**

```
activerecord:
      models:
        business_profile: "Business Information"
        application_setting: "Setting"
      attributes:
        business_profile:
           company_name: "Company Name"
```

**I18n.t(attribute_name)** is not working. It says

> "translation missing: en.company_name"

When the **company_name** is moved out of the active records it works. But I want it to be inside activerecord. How can I translate the attribute the activerecord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@object.class.human_attribute_name(attribute_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
I18n.t(attribute_name, scope: "activerecord.attributes.business_profile")
```

or

```
I18n.t(attribute_name, scope: [:activerecord, :attributes, :business_profile])
```

if you prefer.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

The scope argument contains a dotted string or array of symbols or strings. They match up to a single branch of a tree in the translation YAML file, under 'en'. (Or whatever the current language is.) Effectively they act as a 'path' to the translation.

Certain situations will pick scopes for you, unless you specify one explicitly. For example, in templates it may be the directory path to the template from the view directory onwards. In validations there's a different scope that allows custom messages as well as translations.

Comment: The attribute name can be any attribute. Your answers only works for single hardcoded attribute.

Comment: Oops. It was late and I left the attribute name in the scope, my apologies. Try now.